# Monitoring Object Queues with Boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, ros

I am trying to write a monitoring thread for my application which periodically checks my object queue's length and quits the program if things seem out of control.

At the moment my main runs 2 threads. The relevant sections of the code is as follows :

```
class SolveDGEM {
public:
    SolveDGEM();

    void processQueue();
    void pyramidalFrameQueueConsumer();

private:
    // Queues
    ConcurrentQueue<Eigen::MatrixXf> q_cam0; ///< Thread-safe and fast queue for cam0.
    ConcurrentQueue<ros::Time> q_cam0_time;  ///< Thread-safe and fast queue to hold capture timing for cam0.
    ConcurrentQueue<cv::Mat> q_cam0_cv;      ///< queue to hold cv::Mat for cam0

    ConcurrentQueue<Eigen::MatrixXf> q_cam1; ///< Thread-safe and fast queue for cam1.
    ConcurrentQueue<ros::Time> q_cam1_time;  ///< Thread-safe and fast queue to hold capture timing for cam1.
    ConcurrentQueue<cv::Mat> q_cam1_cv;      ///< queue to hold cv::Mat for cam0

    ConcurrentQueue<Frame> frameQueue;
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int, char **) {
    SolveDGEM dgem;

    boost::thread processQueueThread(&SolveDGEM::processQueue, &dgem);
    boost::thread pyramidalFrameConsumerThread(&SolveDGEM::pyramidalFrameQueueConsumer, &dgem);

    processQueueThread.join();
    pyramidalFrameConsumerThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I am implementing the queue monitoring as

```
void SolveDGEM::monitorQueues() {
    ros::Rate loopRate(1); // once per second

    while (ros::ok()) {
        if (pyramidalFrameQueue.size() > 100 || q_cam0.size() > 100) {
            ROS_ERROR("Queues seem to be groaning without bounds");

            // Code to quit all the other threads

            loopRate.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming I run this function in another boost thread, what is the correct way to quit my application with this thread and safely also quit other 2 threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually just asking how to communicate between threads.

The monitor thread should signal the others in some way (a `condition_variable` or Boost's [thread interruption points](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption) eg.).

The other threads should just cleanly shut themselves down in response to the signal.

Comment: Ok, will have a look at condition_variable